# Getting Maven Compilation Error failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I am getting this error while compiling the JAVA code from **jenkins**.
This doesn't come when I do it from the command line. 
Same environment for JAVA and MAVEN configured for jenkins user both on console and command line shell.

Running on UBUNTU on EC2.

```
[ERROR] **Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) on project website-site: Compilation failure**

[ERROR] Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx2048m

[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Couchbase/site/src/main/java/com/couchbase/components/catalog/LogoGridComponent.java:[10,51] Bool is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release

[ERROR] 

[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) on project website-site: Compilation failure
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx2048m
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Couchbase/site/src/main/java/com/couchbase/components/catalog/LogoGridComponent.java:[10,51] Bool is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed for me. 
Since it was running fine via command line, I increased the memory(ram) on my EC2 instance.
Jenkins was utilizing a lot of memory and hence crashing the compilation.